# Adding Buffered Image into an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedimage

im trying to add my buffered image into an arraylist...
Here I have made my arraylist of type BufferedImage.

```
private ArrayList<BufferedImage> asteroidImage;
```

and I'm trying to add

```
asteroidImage.add(g.drawImage(m_Asteroid, move_Asteroid[i].getX(), move_Asteroid[i].getY(), 50, 50, this));
```

into the array list but am getting an error saying: "The method add(BufferedImage) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)" ... Maybe I'm a bit confused on the actual terminology of everything as I dont understand what the error is trying to say.. any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

[Graphics.drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) returns a boolean, which you are then trying to add to the ArrayList, and that's what's causing your problem. It's hard to say from the limited code snippet that you posted how to solve your issue, but seems like maybe you should be adding m_asteroid to your ArrayList directly.

```
asteroidImage.add(m_Asteroid);
```

Comment: I was going to do that but I have about 10 randomly placed asteroids on the screen... I wanted to be able to identify each of these asteroids with their own index in order to preform some collision detection... if I do: asteroidImage.add(m_asteroid) wouldn't that delete all my asteroids when I decide to remove one that gets destroyed via collision detection?

Comment: No, this shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score -1):

If you look at [the oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) you see that the method Graphics.drawImage returns a boolean, not the image drawed. For this reason, the error says the return value of drawImage is not applicable for the type in the ArrayList - BufferedImage. You can see an example in the link above.